# Javascript check if a variable is set to "true" after end of workstep / process

Tags: javascript, html

I have implemented a speck of code which I don't think that is great according to best practices, because it performs a costant check every half-second whether a variable is set to "true" or "false". 
I am trying to enable a button, following the end of a process to sign documents, but i cannot figure out what is being called after the end of such process. After all the worksteps are completed, a button should appear in order to finish the process and go to the next step.

The javascript snippet is the following:

```
<!-- Enable/disable "Terminate" button-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //Perform a Check on the "Terminate" button in order to enable the "Finish" button 
    $("div#btnCustomFinish").addClass("hidden");

    function checkTermina() {
        if (window.ClientInformation.WorkstepFinishCurrentlyAllowed == false) {
            console.log("Disabled");
            $("div#btnCustomFinish").addClass("hidden");
            //state=0;
        } else {
            console.log("Enabled");
            $("div#btnCustomFinish").removeClass("hidden");
            //state=1;
        }
    }
    //});

    //Enable clicking on "finish" button
    function clickFinish() {
        if (document.getElementById('WorkstepCompletionTaskFinishDocument') != null) {
            document.getElementById('WorkstepCompletionTaskFinishDocument').click();
        }
    }

    //Interval to start the checkTermina function
    setInterval(function() { checkTermina(); }, 500);

     </script>
```

My objective is to implement a better solution in order to achieve the same result but without performing such check after 500 msecs, which could be heavy on the machine.

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT: 
This is the HTML snippet of the 2 buttons, if it helps:

```
<div class="pos-right">
          <div id="btnCustomFinish">
                <img onclick="return clickFinish()" src="images/bt_finish.png">
          </div>

          <div id="btnCustomTerminate">
                <img onclick="return closeconfirmation()" src="images/bt_terminate.png">
          </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of doing all that, just add `window.ClientInformation.WorkstepFinishCurrentlyAllowed = true; $("div#btnCustomFinish").removeClass("hidden"); `, whereever that happens.

Comment: `document.getElementById('WorkstepCompletionTaskFinishDocument').click();` doesn't enable a button to click...it actually clicks the button programmatically without user's consent. Also `document.getElementById('WorkstepCompletionTaskFinishDocument') != null` If that button is there and it's only hidden, that condition will always be true.

Comment: You should add some HTML because it's important to know what's actually there and what isn't. If you have all of this in a `<form>` tag, I have a solution...

Comment: Hi ritaj, zer00ne. To answer your questions respectively:
1) Unfortunately I tried that solution and it doesn't work
2-3) That event clicks another button. This is a workaround in order to make the application work correctly, but that's a topic for another day... I have added the HTML snippet of the 2 buttons, hope it helps, unfortunately no form is used within the page. I was thinking that if this could be solved by using event triggers it would be best (at each event a check is being made).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - you are trying to "watch" a variable for changes and it is ,indeed, a bad approach. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch):

> Deprecation warning: **Do not use watch() and unwatch()**! These two
>   methods were implemented only in Firefox prior to version 58, they're
>   deprecated and removed in Firefox 58+. In addition, using watchpoints
>   has a serious negative impact on performance, which is especially true
>   when used on global objects, such as window. **You can usually use
>   setters and getters or proxies instead**.

Wait a second - `getters` and `setters`? Sounds like a great idea!

```
 function MyState()
 {
    var myValue = false
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'flag',
    {
         get: function() { return myValue }
         set: function(value)
         {
             myValue = value // VALUE CHANGES - DO SOMETHING HERE, for instace:

             checkTermina(myValue) 
         }
    })
 }

 function checkTermina(value) {
    if (value == false) {
        console.log("Disabled");
        $("div#btnCustomFinish").addClass("hidden");
        //state=0;
    } else {
        console.log("Enabled");
        $("div#btnCustomFinish").removeClass("hidden");
        //state=1;
    }
}

var state = new MyState()

state.flag = true // You can set the "flag" value property from whenever you want
```

Yes.. it is a little bit "complex" but it will give you a FAR BETTER SOLUTION and a better coding approach

PS `flag` is not a reserved word - you can change the name to something more meaningful

Comment: Hi ymz, thanks for your response. By going deeper into the issue, it seems that the problem lies within the property of a variable: window.ClientInformation.WorkstepFinishCurrentlyAllowed, which is set as "true" or "false". How do i detect changes to this property? Because the application seems to be changing real-time the value when the workstep process has ended.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is `window.ClientInformation.WorkstepFinishCurrentlyAllowed` method is coded by you? Or can you locate the code behind it in your solution?